# Techniques used when conducting Information Architecture Workshops?

Tags: information-architecture

Which kind of techniques do you use when conducting Information architecture workshops?(e.g. Card sorting) Which were the most useful??

Answer (score 4):

I would like to suggest a few good readings below that can be helpful to you -

- [Information Architecture – SharePoint’s Story](http://www.sharepointedutech.com/2012/04/19/information-architecture-sharepoints-story/)
- [SharePoint Information Architecture and the Information Architect](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joelo/archive/2007/03/16/information-architecture-and-the-information-architect.aspx) (written in 2007 & a classic from Joel Oleson).
- [Information architecture in Office SharePoint Server - Using a scenario-based planning & development.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262985%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [5 Steps to Making SharePoint Information Architecture Work for You](http://www.sharepointpromag.com/blog/sharepoint-pro-by-admins-devs-industry-observers-23/sharepoint/steps-sharepoint-information-architecture-work-142142) (published recently - briefly lists out some good points)

My preference would be to use a scenario-based approach - it displays a practical use-case which can be tailor-made for the client's requirements (or close to it).